# Как изменить иконку приложения Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

При запуске кода на Kivy иконкой приложения по умолчанию служит логотип Kivy. Как его изменить?
Так не получилось:

```
self.icon = r'C:\Users\user\path'
```

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html    class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'myicon.png'
Changed in version 1.8.0: icon is now a StringProperty. Don’t set the icon in the class as previously stated in the documentation.

Note

For Kivy prior to 1.8.0, you need to set this as follows:

class MyApp(App):
    icon = 'customicon.png'
Recommended 256x256 or 1024x1024? for GNU/Linux and Mac OSX 32x32 for Windows7 or less. <= 256x256 for windows 8 256x256 does work (on Windows 8 at least), but is scaled down and doesn’t look as good as a 32x32 icon.

Comment: У основного класса программы

Comment: попробую не png а ico

Comment: После добавления в качестве иконки файл .ico вместо логотипа kivy появился значок командной строки вместе с логотипом python, хотя он не являлся нужным мне файлом

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужна иконка программы в запущенном виде тогда это делается вот так:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','window_icon','path/to/icon.ico')
```

А если иконку программы которая будет на рабочем столе, тогда иконка (логотип) текущего приложения должна быть расположена в том же каталоге, что и ваш основной файл.
И собственно установить ее следующим способом:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'myicon.png'
```